# Implement Search functionality with large data in react native

Tags: react-native, search, pagination, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I have 50K+ records in my db,I want to add search filter without affecting performance of the application .Please suggest me what approach I should adopt to search the large data.

I am calling api to fetch data from server. And used react native search functionality. But due to large data i have implemented pagination at server side so each time new api being called and new data fetched from server. Now issue is it will search only from fetched page records and i want to search from all 50K+ records. And i want to search for each character typed. So  I think it is not fissible to call api at each character typed.

So what is the best approch?

Comment: how about you implement search algorithms at server-side(Obviously server will search faster then RN app). and just call an API to server.

Comment: Probably the best approach is to pass query parameters in your request, handle the filtered research server side and return the already paged data to your application

Comment: To call api after each character typed, It will take more time

Comment: have you researched about search apis which make search simple like algolia and elasticsearch?

Comment: I had a similar case, calling api as user types something, but I set a little delay so that the call started just after the textsearch didn't change for a while (I mean about 0.4 seconds)

Comment: @Nirali You can use debounce function of lodash library for delay api call.

Answer (score 1):

I have a quote finder app which holds 400k quotes on mongodb and I am using Node JS as backend. In my point of view if you are going to search more than 100 items in your front end lets say you are going to use flatlist you can create your searching algoritms in front-end side, than you can dynamically render your list according to search results. 100 items are not a specific limit it is just my idea. Because in lists more data than that would look ugly.

For 50k search you definitely have to come up with search algorithms on server-side. After you get your search data you can use

> https://github.com/UnPourTous/react-native-search-list

And if your specific aim is to search on server-side I would recommend elastic-search.

But for 50k data it is better you implement your own algoritms. When you send fetch request let your server run the search and in response get the data you want.

Comment: is it fissible to call api at each character typed in app search?

Comment: It depends what you want to provide with your app. Google does that, facebook does that, stackoverflow does that. If you want to provide this kind of feature why not. But I would suggest you create a list of 2k result in your front-end. This 2k data has to have key->value relation with the 50k data you keep in database. So in your front-end you can guess what user is looking. Than in your server side since you have the key search will be faster. I know databases have their own algorithms for query actions but you can have an efficient way for both front-end and back-end with this approach.

Comment: What is the meaning of 'This 2k data has to have key->value relation with the 50k data you keep in database.'? Can you explain in detail or with example?

Comment: For example you have 50k soccer players in your database with their name, age, position, team-name, id etc. If you want to search with team-name. You can keep team-names inside an array of 2k long in your front-end. Now instead of fetching and tiring up your server for every character, you can directly guess user input in front-end side. When user choses one of the team-name below that search bar, than one request will be enough to get data. Instead of lets say sending 4.(Real Madrid, Real Sociedad, Real Betis).

Comment: what if user want to search outside that 2k array?

Comment: Then you can check those data with fetching. You can check it for every single character. If you can not come up with approach like front-end key and server value than do it with fetching or directly use search based databases like elastic search. By the way Sir, 50k is nothing, it is almost no data. You can have 10$ server for month and It would handle your searches fast. lets say for 1000 online users a day. Try the solution which is in your head first. Than if something does not happen like you want, you will try new ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use redux for this situation. When you start your application get all records(50+K) from server it will take time(You can get records in splashscreen) based on your server and store all records in redux store. Now you can search data from your redux store so don't need to call API on every search.

Make sure your server send only those data in response which you required to show in mobile application. So for getting records it will reduce response time.

You can use [redux-search](https://github.com/bvaughn/redux-search) for this.

Comment: Storing all records at the client side will be huge performance hit.